# What's the best way to read/write from/to Redshift with Scala spark since spark-redshift lib is not supported publicly by Databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I have my Spark project in Scala I want to use Redshift as my DataWarehouse, I have found [spark-redshift repo](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift) exists but Databricks made it private since a couple of years ago and doesn't support it publicly anymore.

What's the best option right now to deal with Amazon Redshift and Spark (Scala)

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer as I have only been using Spark->Redshift in a real world use-case and never benchmarked Spark read from Redshift performance.

When it comes to writing from Spark to Redshift, by far the most performant way that I could find was to write parquet to S3 and then use [Redshift Copy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) to load the data. Writing to Redshift through JDBC also works but it is several orders of magnitude slower than the former method. Other storage formats could be tried as well, but I would be surprised if any row-oriented format could beat Parquet as Redshift internally stores data in columnar format. Another columnar format that is supported by both Spark and Redshift is [ORC](https://orc.apache.org/).

I never came across a use-case of reading large amounts of data from Redshift using Spark as it feels more natural to load all the data to Redshift and use it for joins and aggregations. It is probably not cost-efficient to use Redshift just as a bulk storage and use another engine for joins and aggregations. For reading small amounts of data, JDBC works fine. For large reads, my best guess is [Unload command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Unloading_tables.html) and S3.

Comment: yeah in our python-spark code we do the same thing we use S3 Copy and S3 load to deal with Dataframe and Redshift, but we found this spark-redshift lib very convenient that's why I was wondering if there are any other libraries like that.
for past4-5 years we have relied on it,